# update listView on a fragment in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-recyclerview

I can't get a listView updated on Android. I have a fragment with a listView, and its items are returned by a REST call.

Here is the AsyncTask:

```
 private class GetMenuPizzeria extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Object[]> {
    private final SelectPizzaFragment.ContentAdapter mListAdapter;
    private final Context appContext;
    private final String pizzeriaId;

    private GetMenuPizzeria(ContentAdapter mListAdapter, Context appContext, String id) {
        this.mListAdapter = mListAdapter;
        this.appContext = appContext;
        this.pizzeriaId = id;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object[] doInBackground(String... params) {
            return pizzeriaManager.getMenuPizzeria(pizzeriaId).toArray();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object[] result) {
        mListAdapter.updateItems(result, appContext);
    }
}
```

and here is the function called onPostExecute (updateItems) :

```
public void updateItems(Object[] newItems, Context appContext) {

            PizzaMenu pm;

            lPizzaNames.clear();
            lPizzaDesc.clear();
            lPizzaPrices.clear();

            Resources resources = appContext.getResources();
            TypedArray a = resources.obtainTypedArray(R.array.place_avator);

            for (int i = 0; i < newItems.length; i++) {
                pm = (PizzaMenu) newItems[i];
                lPizzaNames.add(pm.getName());
                lPizzaDesc.add(pm.getIngredients());
                lPizzaPrices.add(pm.getPrice());
                lPlaceAvators.add(a.getDrawable(0));
            }
            this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Then, I call the AsyncTask like that:

```
GetMenuPizzeria getMenuPizzeria = new GetMenuPizzeria(adapter, this.getContext(), id);
getMenuPizzeria.execute();
```

and that works when I call it the first time, inside the onCreateView of my fragment. 
The problem is, I have to update the list every time the selected pizzeria changes, so I wrote a method:

```
public void updatePizzeriaMenu(String idPizzeria) {
    GetMenuPizzeria getMenuPizzeria = new GetMenuPizzeria(new ContentAdapter(recyclerView.getContext()), this.getContext(), idPizzeria);
    getMenuPizzeria.execute();
}
```

That method correctly calls the AsyncTask and I don't get any errors, except the list is not updated (but notifyDataSetChanged() is called and onBindViewHolder is called as well). I suppose the way I'm retrieving the adapter is wrong or something like that because seems like the list I'm populating everytime I call updatePizzeriaMenu is empty. Could someone please help me and tell me what I'm missing? Thanks in advance

EDIT: here is my adapter class :

```
public static class ContentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {


    private final List<String> lPizzaNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    private final List<String> lPizzaDesc = new ArrayList<String>();
    private final List<String> lPizzaPrices = new ArrayList<String>();

    private final List<Drawable> lPlaceAvators = new ArrayList<Drawable>();

    public ContentAdapter(Context context) {
        Resources resources = context.getResources();
        TypedArray a = resources.obtainTypedArray(R.array.place_avator);
        a.recycle();
    }


    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), parent);
    }

    public void updateItems(Object[] newItems, Context appContext) {
        //see above....
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.avator.setImageDrawable(lPizzaAvators.get(position % lPizzaAvators.size()));
        holder.name.setText(lPizzaNames.get(position % lPizzaNames.size()));
        holder.description.setText(lPizzaDesc.get(position % lPizzaDesc.size()));
        holder.price.setText(lPizzaPrices.get(position % lPizzaPrices.size()));
    }



    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return lPizzaPrices.size();
    }



}
```

Comment: can you post your adapter class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating new adapters each time in `updatePizzeriaMenu(String idPizzeria)` method. but i think, those adapters is not related to any recyclerView through `recyclerView.setAdapter()` method. So do not create new `ContentAdapter` each time instead pass the previous adapter object.

```
public void updatePizzeriaMenu(String idPizzeria) {
    GetMenuPizzeria getMenuPizzeria = new GetMenuPizzeria(adapter, this.getContext(), idPizzeria);
    getMenuPizzeria.execute();
}
```

As you are clearing previous data

```
lPizzaNames.clear();
lPizzaDesc.clear();
lPizzaPrices.clear();
```

and updating new data, it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Sifat, but I was creating a new adapter because the adapter I'm using for the view is not available inside the public method, so I was trying to retrieve it with : 

new ContentAdapter(recyclerView.getContext())

Comment: But new ContentAdapter(recyclerView.getContext()) will give a new instance of the object. It won't give you the previous object, right?

Comment: That's right, so the question is, how can I access to the currently used adapter from a public method inside the fragment? I mean how can I get the current instance of the adapter?

Comment: In which class you have initialize the `adapter` variable? and in which class `updatePizzeriaMenu(String idPizzeria)` method is? aren't they in the same fragment class? If so, then you can declare the `adapter` variable as a global variable.

Comment: thank you Sifat, i solved it like you said, declaring the adapter as global var (in fragment). Resolved.

Answer (score 0):

you haven't updated the adapter in this method, you are assigning some values to some variables, and it doesn't seem to be those variables having any relationship with adapter, you have to set Object in adapter!

for example,

```
 this.setPizzaMenuList(pizzaMenuList); 
 this.notifyDataSetChanged)();
```

will update the ListView.and

```
lpizzaMenuList= pizzaMenuList;
this.notifyDataSetChanged)();
```

won't update the ListView!